Using userform with checbox in Libre write
Good day. I would like to inquire if it is possible to link a userform within LibreOffice Writer to call texts or images using checkboxes. These checkboxes should be linked to a button called "Select" to generate the action of gathering all the selected items and automatically saving them in a new LibreOffice Writer document. Additionally, I'm curious about how to implement this across multiple userforms. I should note that I have no knowledge of VBA code, so I would need a detailed explanation or an example code to follow. I greatly appreciate your attention and assistance with this inquiry. Thank you.
Right now, I'm researching how to link a userform within LibreOffice Writer to use checkboxes and a radio button. Although I have no prior experience with VBA code, I have been exploring tutorials and documentation to understand how I could implement it. I was hoping to find some example or step-by-step guide that would help me correctly configure the userform and link it to the desired actions. However, I am still in the initial phase of exploring and learning about this topic.

"I have no knowledge of VBA code" — Well, that shouldn't be a problem, because LibreOffice macros are typically written in Basic, not MS Office's VBA. Or, for more complex tasks or if you prefer other languages, the UNO API can be accessed with Python or Java instead.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "call" texts or images. It sounds like you have two Writer documents. The first is the source, and it contains all images and text to select from, so maybe it could get very large. Each has a checkbox by it. Then there is a Select button somewhere that, when clicked, copies the images or text that have been checked into a second, new Writer document. Is this right?

Maybe a good solution would be to first put all of the images and text into the source document, and then write code to generate one checkbox for each. Otherwise, creating hundreds of checkboxes by hand and trying to get them to match up to images sounds tedious and error-prone.
